# Python hanging in a loop

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

Thanks to a lot of help from some people, I've got [a threadsafe PyQt gui](http://pastebin.com/GsnA3Xcm), where `sys.stdout` prints to a `QTextEdit` and works fine. Except when a large loop is run in the slave thread.

In a 300,000 iteration loop, I just calculate sqrt, power, and logs, and print the results, but the application just stops and hangs (on my own 64 bit Windows 7 machine, it's after 79%, on an older Mac running Lion it's after ~60%).

Running the loop directly in the python terminal results in the program finishing normally.

I'm not sure I know where to start debugging - is it likely just to be a memory issue, or is there some subtle problem with the threading?

Comment: I'm running the program now (at 5% so far), and yes memory usage is growing. This is not really surprising, since the `QTextEdit` is storing the results of **all** print statements since the program began. I wouldn't have necessarily expected this to crash the program though, rather I would expect it to get extremely slow.

Comment: I'm fairly certain there is a threading issue, but one that I don't understand. I've seen something similar before, and never got to the bottom of it. Perhaps something else has some ideas?

Comment: I guess asking a single element to deal with 2,100,000 print statements is quite a big ask, but I'd have thought there should be a way round it.  In the short term, I shouldn't need to deal with this amount of data (this was just a test) but it'd be nice to know if there's an efficient solution / alternative

Comment: I modified your example to your a `QPlainTextEdit` with a `maximumBlockCount` of 1000. This seems to be running OK with 410,000 iterations done so far (I'm testing it up to 1,000,000 to see if it crashes). Not sure if that is helpful, but I guess it points to the `QTextEdit` as being the problem!

Comment: I should have done some more Googling (http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/qtextedit_gets_a_performance_problem_when_filling_up), but yeh - seems to fix it! I've run a 1000000 iteration loop, taking ~105 mins, and it completed successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As implied in the comments, modifying the `QTextEdit` to a `QPlainTextEdit` fixed the issue; `QTextEdit` is [not designed for handling very large paragraphs](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/qtextedit_gets_a_performance_problem_when_filling_up) , which is effectively what I was creating.  I didn't find it necessary to specify the `maximumBlockCount`